# Transfer data between two html files

Tags: javascript, html

I have two html files. In both html files I have a textarea. The textarea in the first html file is `person.html` has values in the textarea for example `name` and `age` and a `button` which should transfer the content `name` and `age` to the other html file.

The other html file `output.html` has a empty textarea.

How can I transfer the content from the one html file to the other html file?

I just created the two html file with the textboxes like this:

```
<!-- person.html-->
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Persons: </label>
            <textarea id="testInput" class="form-control"
                id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>

<!-- output.html-->
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Output: </label>
            <textarea id="testOutput" class="form-control"
                id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Are these files just directly being opened from file system or do you have a server that is serving these files?

Comment: no they are both openend from the file system. Both files are in my `src` folder

Comment: Are you clicking on a link to get from one file to another, or are you just opening them individualy?

Comment: so I dont have any link :D i just created the two files in my src folder and they have no `EventListener`or something like that. There is just a button in the first html file which should have a `EventListener` to transfer the data from the textarea into the other textarea

Comment: Are you trying to be able to edit one file from the other? Like building a text editor app? There's no straight forward way to access files from the browser, because that's a security risk. You can give them a file picker and have them choose the file to get its contents - but if you really want to open and edit and save the file, you will need the [Native File System API](https://web.dev/native-file-system/), which is experimental.